# docker create service unavailable

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I am behind a corporate firewall, running on Windows 7. I believe that I have gotten past any proxy issues (at least as far as accessing the container for which I'm trying to install.)

At this point I'm trying to execute docker's run command which 'acquires' the tensorflow package an installs it on my system.

$ docker run -it -p 8888:8888 gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: An error occurred trying to connect:
 Post https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.23/containers/create: Service Unavailable.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.

I'm new to docker, (obviously) but I see that the 192.168.99.100 default docker container exists and is running.

I do see documentation regarding the 'create' service endpoint. I'm at a dead end. Any help is appreciated.
-gene

Answer (score 0):

when you type docker command docker client try to connect with your local docker service. And in linux world you need a superuser privileges to connect client and service.
I don`t run docker on windows, but may be you need run docker as Administrator. like linux 
    sudo docker run ...